# Spark SQL DataSource V2 source doesn't support WholeStageCodeGen

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark 3.x, and when I read a csv file or a parquet file(Logical Plan: DataSourceV2ScanRelation, Physical Plan: BatchScanExec), I found that `BatchScanExec` is not extended from `CodegenSupport`,which means that reading from csv or parquet doesn't support code gen support.

I remember in the Spark 2.x, The `FileSourceScanExec` supports whole stage code gen.

I would why the `DataSourceV2` doesn't support whole stage code gen.

Thanks.